# Using command line how to do scaffolding from DB first in ASP.NET - not ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, db-first

I am writing an application that needs to use ASP.NET MVC scaffolding from DB-first  at runtime.

It tests scaffolding from Cli in .NET Core following this link:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

I know how to do this in .NET Core - but I want in ASP.NET MVC - not .NET Core

Comment: Using Entity you should be able to be able to connect to the existing database and have Visual Studio create the mapping and classes between the existing database and the new VS project using the VS menus.

Comment: I know that but i want to make  it from command line because I will make scafooling through another application in run time

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/synchronization/mt490616(v=msdn.10)

Comment: @jdweng I read it but i don't understand  how this help me?

Answer (score 0):

The EntityFramework DbContext used to be a GUI tool that built the DbContext in a fairly straight forward but multi-step procedure. That was the way DbContext model was built in .NET Framework. That tool was removed in the latest .NET "Core" 5. Now it is a single CLI procedure in NuGet's Package Manager named Scaffold-DbContext. i.e.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=win2k22.xxxx.xxxx;initial 
catalog=IdentityWorldDb;user 
id=XXX;password=XXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"  
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
```

That does a nice single step job of creating the DbContext in the Project's Model folder. .NET Core 5's Model folder. I do that as a separate Class project
Then if you create a second .NET Core 5 MVC project in the same solution you can reference the DbContext Model in the Class Project.
This seems to work perfectly for creating Views in MVC but for some reason it isn't currently working with scaffolding Controllers.
Basically EntityFramework seems to be unique between .NET Framework and .NET Core 5 in all respects.